# Non-trivial, time-independent solution at long times for a separable solution of an age-structured model

Tags: partial-differential-equations, biology

I'm taking an introductory course on mathematical modelling in biology and am completely at a loss with this question. We are considering the PDE for a population of cells $n$ with age $a$ over time $t$:

$$\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}+(1+\beta a)\frac {\partial n}{\partial a}=-\mu n$$

with conditions $n(a,0) = f(a)$ and $n(0,t)=2n(1,t)$

I'm meant to seek a separable solution of the form $n(a,t) = e^{(\gamma t)} N(a)$ and then derive an expression for the unique value of $\mu=\mu(\beta)$ such that the population tends to a non-trivial, time-independent solution as $t$ goes to infinity. But surely then $\gamma$ needs to be negative which will lead to 0? And from solving this PDE and substituting in the conditions I found that $\gamma$ cannot be a sum of a negative real number and some linear multiple of $1/t$ which would fulfil the conditions, since $\gamma$ is only a function of $\beta$ and $\mu$ (which is also a function of $\beta$).

Am I missing something obvious? Thanks for the help!

Comment: If the solution at large $t$ is to be time independent, then we can set $\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}$ to zero. Solving the resulting ordinary differential equation yields $n(a)=C(1+\beta a)^{-\mu/\beta}$. Imposing the conditions at $a=0$ and $a=1$ then solving for $\mu$ we find $\mu=\frac{\beta \ln(2)}{\ln(1+\beta)}$. Are you certain there is no typo? Maybe I am mistaken but the problem looks over-determined

Comment: For partial derivatives, use `\partial`, not `\delta`.

Comment: I agree with @Sal . I'm having a hard time making what I'm getting after using the ansatz obey the initial/ boundary conditions.